# :nth-of-type(n) does not work as expected

Tags: css, css-selectors

When using `:nth-of-type(n)` to make a selection it does not return the expected response.

I'm wanting to select the second `<td>` element with className `b`.

Why when using selector `.b:nth-of-type(2)` yield no result?

```
  <div id="foot">
    <table id="nav">
      <tbody>
        <tr valign="top">
          <td class="b"><b>Previous</b></td>
          <td><b>1</b></td>
          <td><a href="#">2</a></td>
          <td><a href="#">3</a></td>
          <td><a href="#">4</a></td>
          <td><a href="#">5</a></td>
          <td><a href="#">6</a></td>
          <td><a href="#">7</a></td>
          <td><a href="#">8</a></td>
          <td><a href="#">9</a></td>
          <td><a href="#">10</a></td>
          <td class="b"><a href="#">Next</a></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
```

#### Stipulations

1. The number of `<td>` elements can change.
2. pure JavaScript/CSS only.

Although `.b:nth-last-child(1)` would work,
this question is to understand why `.b:nth-child(2)` does not return the same.

[Example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/halfcube/S3PQ5/)

Comment: You can't use `nth-of-type` on a class, and there is no `nth-of-class` sadly.

Comment: Do you mean `.b:nth-last-child(1)` and `.b:nth-child(2)` ? Typo ?

Comment: @Sourabh, I do mean `.b:nth-last-child(1)` as this is working code. `:nth-child(2)` does not work for this specific selection either.

Comment: How about using `last-child` or `.b ~ .b`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From **W3C** Specs

> The :nth-of-type() pseudo-class represents an element that has an+b siblings with the same expanded **element name** before it in the document tree, for any zero or positive integer value of n, and has a parent element.

So it looks like you can't use class name to select elements along with this pseudo class.

[**+`:nth-of-type()`**](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Selectors/pseudo-classes/%3anth-of-type)

Comment: Thanks for your research, it is looking like that. However I am sure there must be some work around for now.

Answer (score 0):

as @Sourabh already said, `nth-of-type` isn't correct in this case, `nth-child` (or `last-child` in this case) is the correct way to go. I updated [your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/halfcube/S3PQ5/). Your markup was inconsistent as well. In the first `.b` you have a `<b>` element, while in the second(last one), you had an `<a>` tag.

Comment: Thanks Adam, I'm not concerned about the contents of the `<td class='b'>` elements. I'm wishing to select the second `<td>` with className `b`.

Comment: Then `.b:nth-of-type(2)` or `.b:last-child` is the ticket.