# How to select nth-of-type <td> in Watir

Tags: css, google-sheets, watir

I have the following line of ruby code which makes the first cell in a particular column of a Google Spreadsheet flash up (I'm looking to extract the text as part of the script rather than just make it flash...)

```
browser.element(:css => "[class=s24]").flash        #or
browser.element(:css => "s24").flash                #also works
```

I've been trying without success to incorporate the `nth-of-type` CSS selector, [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18231878/how-can-i-get-some-particular-link-form-the-links-collection).

The following don't work... This seems to be because the `nth-of-type` pseudoclass [doesn't work along with class elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17172391/nth-of-typen-does-not-work-as-expected) :-(

Can anyone suggest how I could go about this instead?

```
browser.element(:css => "[class=s24] nth-of-type(2)").flash
browser.element(:css => "[class=s24] td:nth-of-type(2)").flash
```

Comment: Can you give an example of the html you are working with?

Answer (score 2):

Is there a reason you do not want to use `index`? Something like this:

```
browser.element(:class_name => "s24", :index => 2).flash
```

Comment: which should I would think still work.   when index is combined with other selection criteria, as above, it selects the indexthed item that meets all the other criteria. so that should still work in this case and is more readable code.

Answer (score 1):

**I don't know what `flash` means, but if you can *undo* it, then here is simple solution.**

lets say you have a lots of `td`s in the same container, and you want to target only the second one of a certain class.
I would do it that way..

```
.s24 td ~ .s24 td //selects TD2, TD3, TD4 ... of .s24 class
.s24 td ~ .s24 td ~ .s24 td //selects TD3, TD4 ... of .s24 class
```

So, you can do something like that.

```
browser.element(:css => ".s24 td ~ .s24 td").flash //this will flash all TD2+
browser.element(:css => ".s24 td ~ .s24 td ~ .s24 td").Undoflash //This will undo the flash for TD3+
```

BTW:
you said `browser.element(:css => "s24").flash                #also works`
didn't you mean `".s24"`?